# ImageView which is on the view doesn't appear on Android

Tags: android, titanium

ImageView which is on the view doesn't appear on Android

I have very simple code only setting two Imageview on the view
It works well on iOS

I have confirmed the 'view' is shown properly.
(switch the backgroundColor where I am commented out.)

Is there any defference for nesting view on iOS from android?

in .xml

```
<View id="LowMenu"> 
<ImageView id="LevelLabel" onClick="changeLevel" />
<ImageView id="TweetButton" onClick="clickTweetButton" />
</View>
```

in .tss

```
"#LevelLabel": {
    left:'4%',
    height:'100%',
    width:'40%',
},
"#TweetButton": {
    image:"/img/twitter.png",
    height:'100%',
    right:'4%',
}
"#LowMenu": {
//  backgroundColor:'white',
    height:'10%',
    width:'100%',
    bottom:'1%'

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in android, if you want to show your `ImageView` you must to get file from folder `drawable`, and for adding `id` in android, you must to call `android:id="@+id/` not `android:id="id` this is sample code for `ImageView` in android :

```
   <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/LevelLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
```

Comment: But,another img files are appeared correctly other than images on view,it is titanium.

Comment: what do you mean with titanium?

Comment: Oh,I am using titanium http://www.appcelerator.com/titanium/ which is javascript wrapper to make native code. so I wonder this issue is because of native behavior or titanium issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be done in android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/img2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can customize it as per your need. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

in Titanium and Android, when using ImageView you have to set the path to the image like this: "/images/yourFolder/otherFolder/image.png". Make sure you have the first slash before the path "/images..."